# Moment time difference won't use moment timezone but users computer time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs, moment-timezone

I'm attempting to display a duration ticker for something. The start time is **always** in London time. It works perfectly for people in England/the same timezone, however when people in other time zones look at the duration it displays the wrong value (If you're in a timezone behind England => negative values/too small values, timezone ahead => value too large).

My solution to this was to use moment-timezone. I added the moment timezone data correctly I've attempted to use this timezone data (code simplified and separated into individual lines for easier readability):

```
let londonTimeNow = moment().tz('Europe/London'),
jobStartTime = moment(job.start, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss'),
diff = londonTimeNow.diff(jobStartTime);
duration = moment.duration(diff).format('HH:mm:ss', {trim: false});
```

I was hoping this would then get the current time in London and compare to the start time no matter where you are in the world. However, it seems the `diff` function converts the time to the user's computer time. I tried formatting the `londonTimeNow` to be a string, but then the diff function doesn't work.
Note, I've debugged and `moment().tz()` is working correctly, I've tried with other time zones and it gets the correct time in the zone specified.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**
It seems I can get it working by manually setting the offset property of 'londonTimeNow' to 0. However this doesn't feel quite right to me. I'd prefer a solution that seems less like a hack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify the jobstart time in the same way you declare london time using the same timezone:

```
jobStartTime = moment.tz(jobStart, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss','Europe/London'),
```

This will set the job start time using the same timezone.

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to keep testing it but this seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Could you add expected output or specify what you mean by 'diff converts the time'?
The result of diff is a duration and is not in any timezone.

Other than that, the problem seems to be in not using timezone for task start.
Try this:

```
let londonTimeNow = moment().tz('Europe/London'),
jobStartTime = moment(job.start, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss').tz('Europe/London'),
diff = londonTimeNow.diff(jobStartTime);
duration = moment.duration(diff).format('HH:mm:ss', {trim: false});
```

Comment: By 'converts the time' I mean that despite specifying I want `londonTimeNow` as a time in London (and this variable does get the time in London, even for american users), the diff function seems to notice the time has an offset to the computers local time, and then factors this in. So the result is the diff between their local time and the startTimeString (which is always London time) giving the incorrect value of duration.

Comment: Also thank you, I think you're right about setting the `jobStartTime` to also have a timezone. It seems to work, I'm just going to test more thoroughly before I'm sure.